# Moving armory watching-only .wallet file

Tags: wallet, armory, watch-only

I have set up an offline wallet on computer "A". I set up a corresponding watching-only wallet on computer "B". I have signed and broadcast several transactions. But now I wish to safely move the watching-only wallet to a different computer "C". Then delete the watching-only from computer "B".

- Should I import a digital/paper wallet backup of the watching-only wallet? Is this enough to ensure all existing adddresses and BTC are moved?
- Or should I copy the actual .wallet file manually?

Can this proces be repeated without issues?

Thanks

Comment: For the readers: Armory is a provider of allegedly the "most secure and solid wallet". http://bitcoinarmory.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can just import the watching-only wallet on system "C".  In fact, no reason to remove it from system "B" (if you don't want to).  It's okay to have multiple "watchers" of a given wallet.  Moving the watching-only wallets around doesn't actually move the coins, it just changes which computers recognize coins for which the offline computer has signing authority.

Comment: If after importing the watch-only wallet on system "C", you can simply delete the watch-only wallet on system "B" if you like.